# On Storing Large Base64 Image Data In Local Storage Gives Quota Exceeded Error In JS

Tags: javascript, base64, local-storage

I m using javascript and getting image url in base64 format want to store it temporarily wth localstorage of js but it sometimes give me quota exceeded error in browser console of chrome browser so how can i do that?

I got image path in base64 and shown in console issue i face not able to store it in localstorage func of js if base64 data is too large so i want to solve it for base64 without size limit or quota exceeded error

Comment: The amount of data you can store simply is limited, nothing much you can do about that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_API/Storage_quotas_and_eviction_criteria#web_storage

Comment: You'll have to either place a limit on the size of images, or think of a different design for your application

Answer (score 0):

Try `localStorage.clear()` Method.

From MDN- [Storage: clear() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/clear)